# How to inject react element via chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble to inject react element via chrome extension. Although it may be duplicated, **i have already read some questions in terms of injecting react element via chrome extension and tried a various methods to inject react element.** but it is still not working.

[READ1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734906/add-reactjs-elements-via-a-chrome-extension)

[READ2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599147/proper-way-to-inject-react-component-onto-page-in-chrome-extension)

[READ3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449634/react-js-inject-react-is-not-defined)

Following my code

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "__MSG_name__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "__MSG_description__",
    "author": "Seokjun Hong",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "__MSG_name__"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js",
        "html/emoji_box.html",
        "js/vendor/browser.min.js",
        "js/vendor/react.min.js",
        "js/vendor/react-dom.min.js",
        "js/vendor/react-with-addons.min.js",
        "js/test.js"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "https://github.com/*",
            "https://gist.github.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js",
            "js/content_script.js",
            "js/semantic.min.js",
            "js/test.js"
        ],
        "css": [
            "css/semantic.min.css"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

**test.js (react element)**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { count: 0 };
    },
    handleClick: function () {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1,
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                Click me! Number of clicks: {this.state.count}
            </button>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />,
    document.getElementsByClassName('timeline-comment')[0]
);
```

**content_script.js**

```
(function() {
    //append react script, following trial
})();
```

I have tried to inject react script into content.

**TRIAL1: Injecting script tag using `createElement`**

```
// Adds the react.jsx
var jsx = document.createElement('script');
jsx.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/test.js');
jsx.type="text/babel";
jsx.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(jsx);
```

I also tried following code

```
$(document.head).append('<script src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('js/test.js') + '" type="text/babel"></script>')
```

**TRIAL2: Loading script using `getScript of jQuery`**

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('js/test.js'), function(){
});
```

In this case, I also tried to load all script to execute react code, e.g., `browser.min.js`, `react.min.js`, `react-dom.min.js`.

Various trial returns errors, e.g., `Unexpected Token '<'` or script not loading.

Everything is not working. i don't know **how to inject react element.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that would be using `manifest.json` injection rather Programming injection like `chrome.tabs.executeScript` or inserting script tag.

A sample `manifest.json` as follows,

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "__MSG_name__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "__MSG_description__",
    "author": "Seokjun Hong",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "__MSG_name__"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "react.js",
                "react-dom.js",
                "react-with-addons.js",
                "test.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "all_frames": false
        }
    ]
}
```

test.js

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  displayName: "HelloMessage",

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      "Hello ",
      this.props.name
    );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloMessage, { name: "John" }), document.body);
```

Please be aware in this case you would need to use compiled js rather than JSX.

And if you want to do Programming injection, please **make sure all react related js is injected before you inject your `test.js`**. As for your injecting code, you need to use the same way to inject `react.js` and etc before injecting `test.js`, or just include those files in `content_scripts` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still not working. I follow your manifest.json and load chrome-extension. Error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, occurs in `test.js`.

Comment: @se0kjun, updated, in this case you would need to use compiled js rather than jsx.

Comment: If i use `jsx`, Should i use a bundler such as webpack or gulp?

Comment: @se0kjun, if you want `manifest.json` injection, then you should pre-compile jsx; if using programming injection, then just make sure all the scripts are injected, and I have not tested, but maybe you would need to change `content_security_policy` if react has done something violating the default CSP.